# How can i add an additional class the Drupal’s search form’s submit button?

Tags: theming, search-form, hook-form-alter

I’m trying to add an additional class to the Search form’s submit button. I’m attempting to display a icon font instead of the word Search. The mark-up for this button w/ my added class would be this

```
<input type=“submit” id=“someid” value=“” class=“form-submit flaticon-magnifier12” />
```

i’ve successfully removed the word search from the value field by modifying the search.module file.
i looked for a ref. to the class ‘form-submit’ but it is not in that file.

i also tried the following in the template.php file.

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if($form_id == 'search_block_form'){
    $form[actions][submit][‘#class’] = ‘form-submit flaticon-     magnifier12’;
}
}
```

but that didn’t work!, any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = "form-submit flaticon";
```